# How to run Ajax call on scroll every time when previous ajax call completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling the ajax functions on scroll, The issue I am having is that while scrolling down when a user reaches the point where ajax function is called the ajax call is triggered and while the data/record is being loaded using ajax call the scroll is running the ajax call 100times. What I need is when a user scrolls to a specific point then ajax function calls only once until the record is being retrieved from ajax. After the record is retrieved then the ajax call should trigger again and so on.

```
   jQuery.noConflict($);
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var that = $('#loadMore');
            var page = $('#loadMore').data('page');
            var newPage = page + 1;
            var ajaxurl = $('#loadMore').data('url');
          
          
          
          
    //   
      
      
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100 && $tester == true) {
            
            
            console.log("ajax triggered mobile");
                
              //ajax call
                $.ajax({
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        page: page,
                        action: 'ajax_script_load_more'
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        //check
                        if (response == 0) {
                            //check
                            if ($("#no-more").length == 0) {
                                $('#ajax-content').append('<div id="no-more" class="text-center"><h3>You reached the end of the line!</h3><p>No more posts to load.</p></div>');
                            }
                            $('#loadMore').hide();
                        } else {
                            $('#loadMore').data('page', newPage);
                            $('#ajax-content').append(response);
    
                          
                        }
                    }
                });
              
                
            
            
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this gem somewhere long time ago. Should work for you, let me know.

```
var scrolled = false;
page.on('scroll', function(){
    if(!scrolled){
        scrolled = true;
        //do stuff that should take a while...
        scrolled = false;
    };
});
```